# Cannot initialize Android.Util.Pair inside Gson custom deserializer

Tags: java, android, json, junit, deserialization

I'm creating a `custom deserializer` for my data model in my current application and I getting some problems when trying to initialize a `Pair<>` inside my `CustomDeserializer`. I recover from my Json my items A and B, they are fine and correctly initialized from the `JsonObject`, but when I want to create a `new Pair<>(A,B)` with them I'm getting an exception:

> Method threw 'java.lang.RuntimeException' exception. Cannot evaluate android.util.Pair.toString()

I have been looking to more people with the same problem but I cannot find any tip about this, I don't know why I can't initialize the item inside the `deserializer`. I'm executing all my code inside an `junit` test, so maybe it is caused by that, but I don't know why. Here is the code of my `deserializer`:

```
public class CustomSetDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ExerciseSet> {

   private List<Exercise> exerciseList;

   public CustomSetDeserializer(List<Exercise> exerciseList) {
      this.exerciseList = exerciseList;
   }

   @Override
   public ExerciseSet deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
      List<Pair<Exercise, Integer>> setExercises = new ArrayList<>();
      JsonArray exercisesJsonArray = json.getAsJsonObject().get("exercises").getAsJsonArray();
      for (JsonElement jsonElement : exercisesJsonArray) {
         String name = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString();
         int reps = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("reps").getAsInt();
         Exercise exercise = getExercise(name);
         setExercises.add(new Pair<>(exercise, reps));
      }
      int exercisesPerRound = json.getAsJsonObject().get("exercisesPerRound").getAsInt();
      int restBetweenRounds = json.getAsJsonObject().get("restBetweenRounds").getAsInt();
      ExerciseSet set;
      switch (exercisesPerRound) {
         case 3:
            //TODO TRISET  
            set = new SimpleSet(setExercises, restBetweenRounds);
            break;
         case 2:
            //TODO SUPERSET
            set = new SimpleSet(setExercises, restBetweenRounds);
            break;
         default:
            set = new SimpleSet(setExercises, restBetweenRounds);
            break;
      }
      return set;
   }

   private Exercise getExercise(String name){
      for (Exercise exercise : exerciseList) {
         if (!exercise.name().equals(name)) continue;
         return exercise;
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong exercise name");
   }
}
```

And here's my test:

```
 @Test
   public void read_set_json() {
      CustomSetDeserializer customSetDeserializer = new CustomSetDeserializer(exercises);
      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ExerciseSet.class, customSetDeserializer).enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
      ExerciseSet set = gson.fromJson(setExample, ExerciseSet.class);
      assertThat(set.exercises().get(0).first.equals(exercise), is(true));
      assertThat(set.exercises().get(0).second.equals(12), is(true));
      assertThat(set.rounds(), is(4));
      assertThat(set.restBetweenRound(), is(60L));
   }
```

If I debug my code everything works fine, but the `Pair<>` are never created, so I always retrieve a `List` full of null `Pair<>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Junit test you cannot reference to android code (`android.util.Pair`), due to this test is executed in your local jvm and doesnt have this class to initialize.

Consider use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) lib to mock android classes, or abstract them in your code and dont use concretions(Android Framework class) and use this abstractions and mock them with Mockito.